Health Check gRPC failed to implement
i'm looking at gatling-grpc, running phiSgr's example on my local machine will be fine without any issue, but when i run GrpcExample on GitLab, with local server provided in the example, i encounter this issue log:
07:53:03.046 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.p.GrpcProtocol$ - Couldn't execute warm up request
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:131)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.GrpcProtocol$GrpcComponent.$anonfun$new$2(grpcProtocol.scala:77)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.GrpcProtocol$GrpcComponent.$anonfun$new$2$adapted(grpcProtocol.scala:69)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.GrpcProtocol$GrpcComponent.<init>(grpcProtocol.scala:69)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.StaticGrpcProtocol.createComponents(grpcProtocol.scala:173)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.StaticGrpcProtocol$$anon$2.$anonfun$newComponents$2(grpcProtocol.scala:186)
    at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.comps$1(Protocol.scala:67)
    at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$4(Protocol.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:469)
    at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.components(Protocol.scala:69)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.Call.<init>(Call.scala:19)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.UnaryResponse.<init>(UnaryResponse.scala:16)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.UnaryResponse.<init>(UnaryResponse.scala:27)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.action.GrpcCallAction.<init>(GrpcCallAction.scala:26)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.action.GrpcCallActionBuilder.build(GrpcCallActionBuilder.scala:19)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.$anonfun$build$1(BuildAction.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft(LinearSeq.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft$(LinearSeq.scala:179)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:79)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build(BuildAction.scala:27)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build$(BuildAction.scala:26)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:57)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder.build(PopulationBuilder.scala:93)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.buildScenario(Simulation.scala:195)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.$anonfun$scenarioFlows$1(Simulation.scala:199)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.scenarioFlows(Simulation.scala:199)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.load(Runner.scala:89)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:57)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:89)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:51)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromSbtTestFramework(Gatling.scala:47)
    at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.liftedTree1$1(GatlingTask.scala:51)
    at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.execute(GatlingTask.scala:50)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run.lambda$runTest$1(ForkMain.java:413)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
07:53:03.049 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.p.StaticGrpcProtocol$$anon$2 - Creating a new non-default GrpcComponent with ID b1b9f268-a752-4365-be19-746d8ccbd0c9
07:53:03.049 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.p.GrpcProtocol$ - Making warm up call with method grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
07:53:03.060 [DEBUG] c.g.p.g.g.p.GrpcProtocol$ - Couldn't execute warm up request
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: grpc.health.v1.Health/Check
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:271)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:252)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:131)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.GrpcProtocol$GrpcComponent.$anonfun$new$2(grpcProtocol.scala:77)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.GrpcProtocol$GrpcComponent.$anonfun$new$2$adapted(grpcProtocol.scala:69)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:437)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.GrpcProtocol$GrpcComponent.<init>(grpcProtocol.scala:69)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.StaticGrpcProtocol.createComponents(grpcProtocol.scala:173)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.protocol.StaticGrpcProtocol$$anon$2.$anonfun$newComponents$2(grpcProtocol.scala:186)
    at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.comps$1(Protocol.scala:67)
    at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.$anonfun$components$4(Protocol.scala:69)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:469)
    at io.gatling.core.protocol.ProtocolComponentsRegistry.components(Protocol.scala:69)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.Call.<init>(Call.scala:19)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.UnaryResponse.<init>(UnaryResponse.scala:16)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.request.UnaryResponse.<init>(UnaryResponse.scala:27)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.action.GrpcCallAction.<init>(GrpcCallAction.scala:26)
    at com.github.phisgr.gatling.grpc.action.GrpcCallActionBuilder.build(GrpcCallActionBuilder.scala:19)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.$anonfun$build$1(BuildAction.scala:28)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft(LinearSeq.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft$(LinearSeq.scala:179)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:79)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build(BuildAction.scala:27)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.BuildAction.build$(BuildAction.scala:26)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.ScenarioBuilder.build(StructureBuilder.scala:57)
    at io.gatling.core.structure.PopulationBuilder.build(PopulationBuilder.scala:93)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.buildScenario(Simulation.scala:195)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.$anonfun$scenarioFlows$1(Simulation.scala:199)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:246)
    at io.gatling.core.scenario.SimulationParams.scenarioFlows(Simulation.scala:199)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.load(Runner.scala:89)
    at io.gatling.app.Runner.run(Runner.scala:57)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:89)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:51)
    at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromSbtTestFramework(Gatling.scala:47)
    at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.liftedTree1$1(GatlingTask.scala:51)
    at io.gatling.sbt.GatlingTask.execute(GatlingTask.scala:50)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run.lambda$runTest$1(ForkMain.java:413)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Simulation com.github.phisgr.example.DynamicExample started...

As the log suggests, it could be a problem that a network port got blocked. But i'm not really sure on this issue. Can someone have a look and suggest the solution?
Thank you.

Please add source code and the references to e.g. "running phiSgr's example". The error suggests that your code does not implement the method grpc.health.v1.Health/Check which is part of gRPC Health Checking protocol

@DazWilkin it's a big chunk of code of the author so I can't pass it directly, you can check GrpcExample.scala and TestServer.scala at link https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/phisgr/example/TestServer.scala

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The severity of the log is DEBUG, from which you can infer that the exception is not a problem.

Hi, maybe there is another problem, I will try to get trace log when I get to work.

Hi, I came back with logs but I can only put online here
the log is too big to put in page, please understand and give it a check :-)

I understand the logs of the code I wrote just fine.

but isn't it considerable that on my local I can execute all requests, but in image job it can only run 2 requests only ?
